# tr - Can't create space after comma?

Tags: unix, tr

I'm currently using the line

```
tr '\n' ', ' < test.txt
```

What I'm using is

```
test1
test2
test3
```

becomes

```
test1 ,test2 ,test3 ,
```

but I need to have the space after the comma. tr doesn't seem to recognize anything after the comma at all.

Comment: Just curious, if you do ',x', does it ignore the x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` does single letter to single letter transformations. For multi-character replacements you'll need to use a different tool like sed, awk, or Perl.

In particular, if you read the [man page for `tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr). You'll see that the second argument to `tr` is actually a set and not a multi-character string, and since your first argument to `tr` is only a single character, the second character of the second argument is ignored. Specifically, this quote from the man page is relevant:

> Excess characters of SET2 are ignored.

Probably the reason you are seeing the space before the comma is that your lines have a trailing space.

Here's a Perl-based solution:

```
perl -p -e 's/\n/, /' test.txt
```